# Using Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 together in the same TFS 2008 Project With Check-in Policies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Is this possible?  Right now the Power Tools 2008 check-in policies from Visual Studio 2008 are causing errors with Visual Studio 2010.  In my own work with custom check-in policies it has required referencing different versions of some of the TFS libraries - 9.0.0.0 vs 10.0.0.0 typically.  I'm not really bullish on their being a good solution here, but if anyone knows of one please do share.

> Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the
>   Changeset Comments Policy policy (The policy assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.ChangesetComments,
>   Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not registered.). Installation instructions: To install this policy,
>   follow the instructions in CheckForComments.cs.
>
> Internal error in Custom Path Policy. Error loading the Custom Path
>   Policy policy (The policy assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.CustomPathPolicy,
>   Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not registered.). Installation instructions: Please contact your
>   administrator
>
> Internal error in Custom Path Policy. Error loading the Custom Path
>   Policy policy (The policy assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.CustomPathPolicy,
>   Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not registered.). Installation instructions: Please contact your
>   administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem (though mine was with a custom checkin policy) by having both versions of my custom policy dll installed and then making sure that the 2010 registry entries pointed to the 2010 dll and the 2008 registry entry pointed to the 2008 dll.

Information on where the registry entries are can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx but should be in the path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies

For this to work, both dlls must have the same signatures so it may not be possible with power tools dlls but it works fine with custom policies.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  And yeah I was trying to get custom policies to work in addition to these ones but I thought if I cited those people would just get on my case about what was in them.  :-)

Comment: Which dll are you taking about ? and which are the registry content to which the dll has to be pointed?

Comment: Downvoted for not supplying details of the registry entries nor dlls.

Comment: @Polyfun The dlls were my own custom policy dlls. Apologies for assuming that people compiling their own policy dlls would know about the registry keys needed to get them working.

Comment: @DazEddy - upvoted for updating the answer based on feedback

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools?